# CAPE-sandbox signatures

Tags: sandbox

When I submit a PDF file to analyse, it triggers a signature called `stealth_file`. I just added the alerted path into the whitelist as shown, but it didn't solve the problem.

How to resolve it?
[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be better if you posted text information as text instead of an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by restarting the cape-processor.service

```
$ sudo systemctl restart cape-processor.service
```